# Can we use the multiple databases system concept in a single web application?

Tags: application-design, data-tier-application

Am building a simple web based expert application.I have created two databases in the back-end,One database holds user data and the other holds user activity data.Hence it is accessed by a single web app.[e.g Distributed and Parallel both use in single website for back-end]

**My question:** Can a single web app have multiple databases in the back-end?

Comment: That depends on the DBMS in question: some of them use the term "database" where "schema" would be more appropriate, while others may support only one database per instance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.  You would just create two data sources and potentially two data access layers if you want to take it that far.  At least for .Net/C#/VB.Net this wouldn't be a problem.
I'm not sure I understand the benefit in this case but if you feel you have a good reason to separate the database, there's no reason it can't be done.

Comment: Thanks.Actually am building basing on mysql as back-end.

Comment: I believe MySQL allows for more than one database on an instance, so I don't believe it will be a problem.
What language are you going to be using for the web app?
I'm curious, what is the perceived benefit of having separate databases?  This could add to the complexity of your web app code and may not be worth the effort.

Comment: I will be using couple of languages ie sql,php,javascript and html with css.Though,have failed to come up with the right logic or algorithm to fetch data[ _data synchronization_ ]